# VIMNetworking with pod install error

Tags: ios, objective-c, vimeo, vimeo-api

It's possible use this library with pod install?
My project already uses pod install and when I add this library, crash with:

"(UIImageView+AFNetworking.o) ld: 76 duplicate symbols for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Answer (score 0):

VIMNetworking worked out its Cocoapods issues - see https://github.com/vimeo/VIMNetworking

The Podfile entries that worked for me were

```
pod 'VIMNetworking', '~>5.4.2'

pod 'VIMVideoPlayer', '~>5.4.2'
```

and deleting the line for AFNetworking since the VIMNetworking pulls AFNetworking in as a dependecy.